# Show that the MLE of $\alpha$ is consistent by definition.

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that $(X_1,\dots, X_n)$ is an iid random sample from $X\sim f(x;\alpha, \beta)$ and
$$
f(x;\alpha, \beta)=\frac{\alpha x^{\alpha-1}}{\beta^{\alpha}}, \, 0<x\le \beta, \alpha>0, \beta>0,
$$
Show that the MLE of $\alpha$ is consistent by definition.

---

My work:
Note that the log-likelihood:
$$
\ell(\alpha, \beta)=n\log\alpha-n\alpha\log\beta+\sum_{i=1}^n \log x_i^{\alpha-1} I[1<X_{(1)}<X_{(n)}\le \beta]
$$
where $X_{(1)}\le X_{(2)}\le \dots \le X_{(n)}$.

Then the MLE of $\beta$ is
$$
\hat{\beta}=X_{(n)}.
$$

By the invariant of MLE and solving $\frac{\partial \ell(\alpha, X_{(n)})}{\partial \alpha}=0$, the MLE of $\alpha$ is
$$
\hat{\alpha}=\frac{1}{\log X_{(n)}-\frac{1}{n}\sum \log X_i}
$$

By Weak law of large number, we have
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum \log X_i \to E[\log X_1]=\log \beta-\frac{1}{\alpha}.
$$

Note that for every $\epsilon>0$,
$$
P(|X_{(n)}-\beta|>\epsilon)=P(\beta-X_{(n)}>\epsilon)=\frac{(\beta-\epsilon)^{n\alpha}}{\beta^{n\alpha}}\to 0
$$
as $n\to \infty$. (Because $\frac{\beta-\epsilon}{\beta}<1$)

Hence, $\hat{\beta}=X_{(n)}\to \beta$ in probability.

Hence, by continuous mapping theorem
$$
\hat{\alpha}=\frac{1}{\log X_{(n)}-\frac{1}{n}\sum \log X_i}\to \alpha
$$

Is my proof right?